# El-input Field does not react to keyboard input

Tags: vue.js, element-ui

I am creating a small vocabulary trainer in vue. The Vue component should load a list of German Spanish vocabulary from a file. The array from the json file contains objects with a field for the Spanish word and a field for the German word. I wanted to make a deep copy of the array and add a field to the array to store the corresponding translation the user entered. Unfortunately the input field where the user should write the German translation into the field vocabulary.answer does not react on user input. The field seems to be readonly. The code of the component looks like this:

```
<template>
  <div v-if="vocabularies">
    <div v-if="!isValidate">
      <el-row
        v-for="vocabulary in vocabularies"
        :key="vocabulary.id"
        justify="center"
        type="flex"
      >
        <el-col :span="2">
          <span class="spanish-value-label">{{ vocabulary.spanish }}</span>
        </el-col>
        <el-col :span="4">
          <el-input
            v-model="vocabulary.answer"
            class="valid-answer"
            placeholder="Put your answer here"
          />
        </el-col>
      </el-row>
      <el-row justify="center" type="flex">
        <el-button
          class="submit-button"
          onSubmit="{onSubmit}"
          plain
          @click="onSubmit"
        >
          Check vocabluaries
        </el-button>
      </el-row>
    </div>
    <div v-else>
      <el-row
        v-for="vocabulary in vocabularies"
        :key="vocabulary.id"
        justify="center"
        type="flex"
      >
        <el-col :span="2">
          <span class="spanish-value-label">{{ vocabulary.spanish }}</span>
        </el-col>
        <el-col :span="4">
          <el-input
            v-model="vocabulary.answer"
            disabled
            placeholder="Put your answer here"
          />
        </el-col>
        <el-col :span="4">
          <el-icon
            v-if="vocabulary.answer === vocabulary.german"
            class="right-answer"
          >
            <Check />
          </el-icon>
          <el-icon v-else class="wrong-answer">
            <Close />
          </el-icon>
        </el-col>
      </el-row>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div v-else>
    <el-row justify="center" type="flex">
      <el-col :span="4">No vocabularies found</el-col>
    </el-row>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { computed, defineComponent, onMounted, ref } from "vue";
import data from "@/assets/vocabularies.json";

export default defineComponent({
  setup: function () {
    const isValidate = ref(false);

    const vocabularies = computed(() => {
      return data.map((vocabulary) => {
        return {
          spanish: vocabulary.spanish,
          german: vocabulary.german,
          answer: "",
        };
      });
    });

    const onSubmit = () => {
      isValidate.value = !isValidate.value;
    };

    return {
      vocabularies,
      answer,
      isValidate,
      onSubmit,
    };
  },
});
</script>

<style>
.submit-button {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
</style>
```

When i use anoter variable for example:

```
const answer = ref("");
```

And use it like this:

```
          <el-input
            v-model="answer"
            class="valid-answer"
            placeholder="Put your answer here"
          />
```

it works. So I am quite clueless why it's does not work with the array version.

Comment: Computed properties are read-only. Use reactive/ref instead for v-model to work.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Bernard Borg for your answer. I have now modified the code as follows, which has solved my problem:

```
const vocabulariesWithAnswer = ref([]);

onMounted(() => {
  vocabulariesWithAnswer.value = data.map((vocabulary) => {
    return {
      spanish: vocabulary.spanish,
      german: vocabulary.german,
      answer: "",
    };
  });
});
```